# ECG-Lead 1 vs Lead 2

Tags: electrocardiogram

I am new to this and I am trying to do some filtering on ECG signals.
I am working on Lead I signals but they appear too noisy. However, Lead II singals appear significantly less noisy whilst having similar shape to Lead I.
Why is that? I would expect that they differ but they are suprisinlgy similar. What should the differences be?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Medical Sciences! Questions here are required to show results of prior research. As described in the [help] and [this meta post](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/411/is-it-ok-to-ask-questions-that-dont-show-any-research), this demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and helps you get more specific and relevant answers. Please edit your question with links to or references to what you've found in your search. Otherwise your question may be closed.

Comment: There are _many_ ECG primers available on the web that answer your question. In fact, if you google "lead I vs lead II" the first hit explains what they are. As for the noise, movement or a poorly adhering electrode are the usual culprits.

Comment: Hello. I have done research but from my understanding each each ech from a 12-lead ecg is expected to look different, but lead 1 seems almost identical to lead 2 but with more noise. I dont have a medical background so i was wondering whether someone knows.